# Is there a search engine friendly way to combine server side rendered HTML with a client side MVVM/MVC framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, html-rendering

(**EDIT:** I've changed this question because of some confusion and it's maybe a duplicate now and current answers may not make sense, sorry for that)

Many modern js libraries, e.g angularjs, emberjs, reactjs, ractivejs, riotjs, use a similar pattern. Which is specify container, define a template, get some data that fits with template and then render HTML in the container using the template and data.

This will give you an empty container on first page load before the javascript does its magic, not very search engine friendly. I know about some tools to get around this problems e.g https://prerender.io/

I'm using .net mvc and for ReactJS I've found this solution http://reactjs.net/guides/server-side-rendering.html "pre-render the initial state of your React components server-side" and I guess that solves the problem for reactjs.

Are there similar solutions for other js libraries? or is this not an big issue since those libraries are supposed to be used only for SPA?

(I've had a quick look at flight.js as well which may be a better fit for me http://flightjs.github.io/ )

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply have your model serialized out as json within javascript.

Render your views the same way as you would with the MVVM of your choice.

To render the view model use this approach:

```
  var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

With your example this would become:

```
var sampleComments = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

var ractive = new Ractive({
                          el: example,                                  
                          data: {
                            comments: sampleComments
                            }
              });
```

If you were to use knockout, you could then do the following:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var viewModel = new AViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then you would use standard ko bindings on the page.

In order to get two way binding in knockout I simply make sure that the naming convention of the properties match.

As an example in a collection index them to keep the model binder happy i.e.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Comments">
                <tr>    
                    <td><input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Comments[' + $index() + '].Author' }, value: Author" /></td>
                    <td><input data-bind="attr: { name: 'Comments[' + $index() + '].Content' }, value: Content" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: That would render the HTML for the comment list by the client which is what I want to avoid. Maybe I was unclear about that.

Comment: @MartinLarsson Sorry, with the above you have to do rendering with your MVVM. Is that not what you meant?

Comment: Not really, sorry I'm having trouble expressing my thoughts :) In your example with the knockout code I would want the full table to be loaded on  first page load server side. Not just one "tr template" and then fill it from an array with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not make sense.. :)

Ractive needs to have a template and the data to do some looping. It can't generate data/template from a given content.

But as mentioned above, you can put all the data in a js variabel, and do the rendering with that. I don't think that your users will experience any 'speedbumps' with that approach.
Actually you will download less bytes from the server, as you only download the template once instead of for each line.

Comment: On the Website I want to use it on I get 90% of the traffic from search engines. Search engines will only see an empty <ul>  if I load the comments with javascript. That's why I want the "initial state" to be prerendered. https://prerender.io/ exists because of this problem, but I don't want to use something like that I want a nicer solution if there is one.

Comment: If your page is primerarly a "readonly" page, i would keep the serverside rendering. You could also take a look at "hashbang !#"  wich google use to index "javascript driven" pages.

Comment: I would say most pages are hybrids, don't you think? Or is everyone suddenly building single page applications and that's the only thing these js libraries can/should be used for? I think the author of this article says it well with this sentence "When the page loads, it should render in HTML, but it should boot up and become interactive when loaded by the browser." - https://medium.com/@ericflo/facebook-just-taught-us-all-how-to-build-websites-51f1e7e996f2